# Non Linear non homogenous Partial Differential Equation boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristics

I have some problems here. The first involves what I believe is called **Burger's Equation**, but in any case, I have a partial differential equation to solve, and all I would like to find out is the step by step process of going about it, so I can work it out myself. We have **u times δu/δx + δu/δt = 2**. The initial conditions are given as **u(x, 0 ) = -x**. We are first asked to find the **Characteristic Curves**. What I did was use the **Chain Rule**, and went about as follows :

To begin with, let us look at the **Chain Rule** to see if we can make the equation above fit the pattern it gives. 
For this we have :

**du/dt=δu/δx times dx/dt + δu/δt times dt/dt**, and so, to give it a solution more conducive to this, we make sure that the **u** in the problem is analogous to the **dx/dt** in this variation of **Burger's Equation**, both being the coefficients of **δu/δx** , and the **2** from the **Right Hand Side** of the problem is like the **du/dt** in the Chain Rule expression, and it is obvious that **dt/dt=1**.

So  **dx/dt times δu/δx +  δu/δt = du/dt**  compared to  **u times δu/δx + δu/δt = 2**  makes **u=dx/dt**,  and **du/dt=2**. For a start, this means that along the characteristic lines, **u** changes for each second with a **slope of two**, where if we integrate  **du/dt=2**, and get **∫(du/dt) dt=∫2dt**, we end up with **u=2t+A** , with **A** some constant, or function not dependent upon **t**, and at **t=0**, because the initial condition states that **u(x,0)= -x**, then **A= -x**, while for **u=dx/dt**, this implies that **x=ut+B**, with **B** a constant of integration or function not depending on **t**, since **dx/dt= d/dt(ut)=u**.

I also went on to add : From the information above, since **u=2t+A,∀t∈R∶t ≥0**, and it was found that **A= -x**, then **u=2t-x**. But since it is also known that **x=ut+B**, and if we rearrange **u=2t-x**, we can also shew that **x=2t-u**, then **ut+B= 2t-u**.

Now out of this, which are the characteristic curves ? Are they the lines **x=ut+B**, and **u=2t-x**, or have I totally mucked this up ? At what stage also should I have put in the change of coordinate variables with **t=tau** and **x=xi** ?

We are required next to find the solution **u** in terms of the original variables **x** and **t**, but I am fuzzy on how to relate this to the chain rule equation. We are also to go on to sketch this, and I assume these are lines in the plane.

We are also asked to consider this same initial value problem but with a new initial condition that **u(x, 0) = f(x)**, where **f'(x)** is bounded, then to find those characteristic curves and from the **Jacobian**, determine the earliest possible time at which the solution will break down.

We are also informed that it is not possible to find an explicit form of **u** as a function of **x** and **t** but it *is* possible to find an implicit solution **F(x, t, u)** = 0, and we are asked to find it, and I have been looking at YouTube videos all weekend to work out the procedures for solving PDE'S like these, but I am still not sure how to proceed.

Finally, we are asked to consider the initial value problem **δu/δt - u squared times δu/δx = 0**, with initial conditions in a piecewise, Heaviside type set up,  **u(x, 0) = g(x) = { negative half, if x less than or equal to zero ; 1 if x between zero and 1 exclusive ; and one half when x is greater than or equal to one }**

From this we are asked to sketch or plot those base characteristics, then find the solution, as well as determine in which region it is single-valued. Next we sketch or plot the solution for **t = 0, 2, 4**, and finally find the shock solution for this system.

I have some ideas, but I just need some hints to put it all together, in the way of some step by step procedures. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In your integration of u you are confosing the initial value (at t=0) of x and its vakue at a later time. From $u=dx/dt$ and $u=2t-x_o$ one gets $x(t) = t^2 -x_0t + x_0$, i.e.: $u(t^2 -x_0t + x_0, t) = 2t-x_0$. Now, given $x,t$, you can solve for $x_0$ and write the solution $u$ in terms of $x,t$ to get $u(x,t) = 2t - (x-t)/(1-t)$ for small $t$.

Comment: Thank You. I will have a look at that.

Comment: If anyone has any other ideas, I will be glad to hear them. Thank You.